# GeoPandas and OSMnx- plotting on map

Tags: python, dictionary, plot, geopandas, osmnx

I want to plot my Geopandas df on a map. as a background i want a (road) map of the area. loving the OSMnx package, i'm trying to figure out how to use it's output (shapefile? network?) as my plot background

```
import osmnx as ox 
G= ox.core.graph_from_place('Chengdu City', network_type='all_private', 
                            simplify=True, retain_all=False, 
                            truncate_by_edge=False, name='unnamed', 
                            which_result=1, buffer_dist=None, timeout=180, 
                            memory=None, 
                            max_query_area_size=2500000000, 
                            clean_periphery=True, infrastructure='way["highway"]', custom_filter=None)
```

this is the network graph, now i want to plot my geopandas points (and lines) on it:

```
dict= {'take_lat_1k': [31.47, 31.51, 30.54, 30.54],'take_lng_1k': [104.75, 104.67, 103.97, 103.97], 
     'return_lat_1k': [31.48, 31.49, 30.54, 30.54],'return_lng_1k': [104.71, 104.69, 103.97, 103.97]}
df= pd.DataFrame(dict)
# creating Geopandas geometries 
geometry_t = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df["take_lng_1k"],df["take_lat_1k"])]
geometry_r = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df["return_lng_1k"],df["return_lat_1k"])]
lines = [LineString(ab) for ab in zip (geometry_t, geometry_t)]

# osmnx network as the fig,ax
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)

# creating Geodf
geo_df_t = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry_t)
geo_df_t.plot(ax=ax, markersize = 20, color = "red" , alpha=1)
geo_df_line = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=lines)
geo_df_line.plot(ax=ax,  color = "black"  , alpha=1  )
geo_df_r = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry_r)
geo_df_r.plot(ax=ax, markersize = 20, color = "green"  , alpha=1    )
plt.show()
```

and what i'm getting is the pretty osmnx netwrok graph, but without my points and lines between them. also this appears at the bottom of the image:  *Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes* 
 
am I doing this right..?

Answer (score 3):

Per the [OSMnx documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.plot.plot_graph) use the `show` and `close` arguments to prevent showing and closing the plotting figure before you've added everything to it. Also, give your points and lines a higher zorder to ensure they're plotted on top of the basemap rather than under it:

```
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, show=False, close=False)
geo_df_t.plot(ax=ax, markersize = 20, color="red" , alpha=1, zorder=7)
geo_df_line.plot(ax=ax, color = "black", alpha=1, zorder=8)
geo_df_r.plot(ax=ax, markersize = 20, color="green", alpha=1, zorder=9)
plt.show()
```